# Can .Net Compact Framework 2.0 be installed on a Windows Embeded Handheld 6.5 Classic terminal?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded, compact-framework2.0

I have a customer with files that are to be installed on a Unitech PA986-II terminal (CPU Marvel PXA320), but some of the packages will not install because .Net 2.0 is not present. So far I have been unable to find a version that will install.

The about information says that it is running CE OS 5.2.23152 Build 23152.5.3.12. The cgccutil reports that .NET Compact Framework 3.5.9198.0 is installed.

I've tried NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab but that fails after the installation starts, but before it asks for a location.

Answer (score 0):

Side-by-side installation is supported, but largely unnecessary because the CF 3.5 runtimes are capable of running CF 2.0 assemblies.  In over 90% over of the cases I've seen, the 2.0 stuff just works with no intervention.

Since you're asking, I'm going to assume you fall into the other 10% and your application isn't running.  In those cases you can either explicitly tell the app to run under 3.5 by putting this in the app.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v3.5.9198"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Or you can force the 3.5 runtimes to use 2.0 compatibility mode by putting this into your app config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <compatibilityversion major="2" minor="0"/>
  </runtime>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v3.5.9198"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

[More info on configuring the runtime is available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but one of the failure occurs during the installation of SQL Server Client 2.0. The error is that it is trying to find .NET 2.0 happens during the installation.

Comment: what's the file name of the CAB file you're trying to install and is failing?

Comment: It is NETCFv2.wm.armv4i.cab- Windows Mobile was the only one I could find. I got it to install by modifying the cab settings. Now the SQL Client installs. The target application fails nicely now, but I don't know yet what it doesn't like. Too many unknowns.

Comment: Strike that I didn't need to edit it. The wm version installed unmodified without error.

Comment: My point was that you likely don't need to install CF 2.0 at all because 3.5 is already there and capable of running 2.0 applications.

Comment: I understood that, but the issue was the installer failed for the product without it. I didn't see anything in the CAB header that caused it to check.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `NETCFv2.wm.armv4i.cab` from the Compact Framework 2.0 SP2 SDK. Even though this is not a Windows Mobile machine it installed. I edited the original file, `NETCFv2.wce5.armv4i.cab`,  using Win CE Cab Manager removing the PocketPC restriction. That had prevented it from running before. It failed during installation.

After installing the Mobile version the SQL Client 2.0 installed without error.

For what it's worth - both cab files are set to CE 6.999 as the upper bounds it could install to.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your application using visual studio 2008, it automatically installs SQL mobile and compact framework, at least on windows embedded ce 6.0.

Comment: That's not very useful for deployment, unless you expect the customer to hook Studio up to every device they field.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in VS 2008 you can create a smart device CAB project and it will include everything you need for your application, so that customers can install the app without having VS.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Does following this advice result in .Net 2.0 being installed on the Win-CE device?

Comment: Theoreticaly, yes. Since it works with windows apps, it should also work for win-CE.